# Is it possible to limit knowledge search results to a data category group in an Experience Site (help center)?

Tags: knowledge, customer-portal, lightning-knowledge, experience-builder-page

We've created an experience site designed to be a knowledge base/help center. The articles have public visibility, but we were hoping to create an experience site with member-only knowledge articles.

During setup, we limited the experience site to one data category group. This works fine for the on-page list components but the search component returns knowledge articles regardless of data category group.

Is there a way to limit this search to certain data category groups?

[image: help-center-search]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this. In order to limit what the global search component returns, we have to edit the profile that's viewing the search results. If it's a completely public Experience Cloud site, this means editing the guest user profile that's automatically generated as part of the site creation.

Editing the category visibility settings for this guest user profile then determines the articles shown when using the search component.

Comment: could you share a little more on how you achieved this?

Comment: @Ray - If you click on the Settings tab in the Builder for the Experience Site, at the bottom of the General tab will be a link to the Profile that's used for any guest or unauthenticated users who visit the Experience Site. You can then edit this profile's catagory visibility settings so it can onlly view the categories you want it to view. The search component will then only return results that fit this criteria.

Comment: Have done this, access site's Guest Profile via the link to profile in Builder.   Have got 1 data category set to No Access, and another set to Custom with a particular node selected.   There are only 2 test articles with that node Data Category.  However still getting lots of search results for articles with no data category at all??  Any idea?

Comment: Got this from Support saying can't restrict visibility to data categories on profiles (e.g. site guest profile),   so is your solution still working?

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ0exAAC/doc-fix-unable-to-restrict-data-category-visibility-settings-with-only-profiles